# Surface area of parabolic helicoid

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

A helix is a curve that climbs around the surface of a cylinder and the associated helicoid. $$<r cos \theta,rsin\theta,\theta> ,0\le\theta\le2\pi$$Consider a helix-like curve climbs on the surface of a paraboloid of revolution $$z^2=x^2+y^2$$
What is the length of parabolic helix-like curve and the surface area of parabolic helicoid-like surface?

So first I need to find the equation of the helix-like curve, the equation of a cylinder helicoid is $$<r cos \theta,rsin\theta,\theta> ,0\le\theta\le2\pi$$ I assign the value $$z=\theta$$and because $$r=x^2+y^2, and z=x^2+y^2$$
so I think the equation of parabolic helix-like curve should be
$$<\theta cos\theta, \theta sin\theta, \theta>$$
and I am stack here, so to find the surface area of a normal helicoid, we shoud find $$df/dr,df/d\theta$$right, but for this parabolic helicoid-like surface, I only have one variable theta, how should I find the surface area of this parabolic helicoid?

Comment: What is your general definition of a 'helix around a surface'?

Comment: It is a helix curve climbing on the surface of a paraboloid of revolution. So like a normal helix curve is climbing on the surface of a cylinder and the associated helicoid. @DavidP

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation of paraboloidal helicoid is

$r(t, s) = (t s \cos s , t s \sin s, s^2 )$

where $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ t \in [0, 1] $

Surface area over $s \in [0, s_1] $ equals

$\text{Surface Area} = \displaystyle \int_{s = 0 }^{s_1} \int_{t=0 }^{1} \| r_t \times r_s \| dt ds $

Where

$r_t = \dfrac{\partial r }{\partial t} = (s \cos s, s \sin s, 0 ) $

$r_s = \dfrac{\partial r }{\partial s } = (t (\cos s - s \sin s), t (\sin s + s \cos s) , 2 s ) $

The cross product comes to

$r_t \times r_s = (2 s^2 \sin s , - 2 s^2 \cos s , t s^2 ) $

So,

$\| r_t \times r_s \| = s^2 \sqrt{ 4 + t^2 } $

Integrating over $t$ gives a factor of $\approx 2.0805$

And then integrating over $s$ gives the final area as

$\dfrac{2.0805}{3} s_1^3 = 0.6935 s_1^3 $

Comment: Is the t in the equation the radius? Why it has a limit from 0 to 1? And why there is a s^2 rather than s in the equation

Comment: The helix equation on the surface of the paraboloid is $( s \cos s , s \sin s, s^2 )$.  This point lies on the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2 $.  What remains is to span the distance between the $z$ axis and this point, and this is achieved using the $t$ parameter.

Comment: What I thought is that the equation for a cylinder helicoid is (rcos s, rsin s, s). and the equation for a paraboloid of revolution is z = x^2 + y^2. I let the height of them be the same z = s. So to make a parabolic helicoid, I made the equation (scos, ssins, s) so that radius of helicoid will increase as height increase

Comment: In a parabolid, the $z$ coordinate is equal to the square of the radius.